# update-alternatives broken and php no longer found in cmd

Tags: php

I tried to switch the php version from 7.4 to 8.0 on my ubuntu operating system and wanted to use update-alternatives. I entered the following command, which broke everything:
`sudo update-alternatives --install /etc/alternatives/php php /usr/bin/php8.0 1`

This command must have been faulty, because now php is no longer found through cmd and any update-alternatives command returns `update-alternatives: error: cannot stat file '/etc/alternatives/php': Too many levels of symbolic links`

It must have something to do with the php-symlink under /etc/alternatives. It is marked as `Link (broken)` and the Link target is `/etc/alternatives/php` which is the file itself, brobably resulting in an infinite loop. Deleting the file and running update-alternatives again recreates the file, but with the same broken link target.

Any information on how to fix this is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What is that `1` being used for in `/usr/bin/php8.0 1`? Would `sudo update-alternatives --auto php` reset to an earlier version and make PHP available again?

Comment: When I googled how to use update-alternatives it gave me this: ``update-alternatives --install <link> <name> <path> <priority>``. I set the "1" as "priority".

I tried ``sudo update-alternatives --auto php`` but it returns the same error:  ``update-alternatives: error: cannot stat file '/etc/alternatives/php': Too many levels of symbolic links``

Comment: `update-alternatives --config php`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was recommended to run `update-alternatives --auto php` or `update-alternatives --config php` which did not work for me. What worked however was this:

1. I manually deleted the faulty symlink under `/etc/alternatives/php`
2. I ran `sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/php php /usr/bin/php8.0 1` which, in contrast to the other commands, created a new and working symlink to the corresponding php version.

This restored normal functionality of update-alternatives and made me able to use php from cmd again.